# How do I join Aternos server Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

When I try to join it says something like "Hello, Roxy Kat Gaming. The server you tried to join isn't there" and I copied and pasted the server IP from the aternos website.

Comment: This seems like an issue with Aternos, rather than a problem with Minecraft. As such I would recommend reaching out to them as long as other servers work fine

Comment: @Topcode Yeah no other aternos or minehut servers work not even ones I don't own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the server started?

If so, is the server the same version of Minecraft as your client? (e.g. the server is running 1.18.1 and your client is running 1.15.2; this scenario won't work unless you install `ViaBackwards`

Also try restarting your device, the game, and the server.

Answer (score 2):

The server has to be open in order for you to join. You have to press the large prominent green "Start" button in the server dashboard, or if you're not the owner, ask the owner to do it.